How can I create and later update AD users in Active Directory from a CSV file when they have the same name?
I want to import many users from a CSV into my Active Directory. Each user in the CSV has a first name, last name, username (e.g. silas.küng) primary class, and secondary class.
Is it possible to import users into Active Directory and, when two users have the same first and last name, add a number (e.g., "1") to the second user's username? Later, during future imports, can I still differentiate between these users so that I can update them individually (e.g., if their classes change)?
I believe this is not feasible because how can I differentiate between them later when the users in the CS don’t have a unique ID or something? The classes could change.

For that (to be at the safe side) you indeed will need to add an unique id as the SID (Security Identifier)), samAccountName, DN (Domain Name) or CN (Common Name) to the csv list.
